How do I define the vertical position of all subtitles across an entire sequence in Premiere 2024
I'm using the modern subtitling system built into Premiere 2024
I want to adjust the vertical position of all subtitles in my sequence.
My steps:

Double click the subtitle to be altered
Adjust the y position in the Alight & Transform panel in Essential graphics.
Save the Track Style in the Essential Graphics panel
Click Redefine Style in the panel.
Apply to All Captions on Track

None of the other subtitles are adjusted vertically.
Video example:
https://vimeo.com/956604482/f5994c8041
